# Problema bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap, angular

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un sitio web, y tengo un problema.
Estoy haciéndolo con Angular y bootstrap.
La pagina principal consta solamente de un navbar un cuerpo de noticia y el footer
pues al crearlo consigo que el footer y el cuerpo de noticias me queden del mismo largo pero el navbar me queda un poco mas chico aunque estoy marcando que use las 12 columnas igual que con los otros 2 elementos.

app.component.html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <app-navbar></app-navbar>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <app-footer></app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

navbar.component.html:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['menu']">Menú</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['about']">Sobre Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item">                                                      </li> -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

footer.component.html:

```html
<footer class="page-footer font-small mdb-color lighten-3 mt-3 color">

    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mr-auto my-md-4 my-0 mt-4 mb-1 ml-3">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Información</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <p class="letras">Info de Me Tente</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto my-md-4 my-0 mt-4 mb-1">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Dirección</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-home mr-3"></i> Montevideo, UY xxxxx, UY
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope mr-3"></i> info@example.com</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone mr-3"></i> 09xxxxxxx</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center mx-auto my-4">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Siguenos</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/metentefood/">
                    <i class="socialmedia colorF animation fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/me_tente.food/?hl=es-la" class="ml-2">
                    <i class="socialmedia colorI animation fab fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<br>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between">
        <div class="card col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1 justify-content-center">
            <!--ml-lg-3-->
            <img class="card-img-top pt-2 pb-2" src="../../../assets/img/postre1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1">
            <!--mr-lg-3-->
            <article>
                <h2>BASES</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam tempora nemo ducimus quis obcaecati praesentium enim inventore molestias possimus asperiores, totam impedit, consectetur porro modi quo officia soluta rem iste!</p>
                <h3 class="firma">Quilia Lozano</h3>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

home.component.html:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between">
        <div class="card col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1 justify-content-center">
            <!--ml-lg-3-->
            <img class="card-img-top pt-2 pb-2" src="../../../assets/img/postre1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1">
            <!--mr-lg-3-->
            <article>
                <h2>BASES</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam tempora nemo ducimus quis obcaecati praesentium enim inventore molestias possimus asperiores, totam impedit, consectetur porro modi quo officia soluta rem iste!</p>
                <h3 class="firma">Lorem</h3>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

navbar.component.css:

```html
#navbarNav {
    background-color: #F4EFE1;
}

#navbarNav .navbar-brand,
#navbarNav .navbar-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A1C13;
}

#navbarNav .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A1C13;
}

#navbarNav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
#navbarNav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #F4EFE1;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #3A1C13;
}
```

Comment: Debes tener algo más en tu CSS que no nos estás mostrando, este es tu código en codepen: https://codepen.io/JheyMejia/pen/YROaZe?   Uso Angular.js, Bootstrap 4.1 y Material Desing for Bootstrap (MDB), todos por CDN. No veo ningún error aparente

Comment: Actualice el post con el código css que afecta al navbar. lo probé en cedepen y funciona bien. pero no entiendo el porque al pasarlo a mi proyecto se ve así

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la clase `.navbar` de Bootstrap, que por defecto trae la propiedad `padding: .5rem 1rem`. Debes modificarla (o eliminarla) para que se alinea al borde de las columnas.

Si vas a modificar, lo puedes hacer quitando los *paddings* correspondientes a la izquierda y derecha:

```
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
```

Aunque se recomienda usar 1 sólo `padding` "global":

```
padding: .5rem 0;
```

---

Recuerda ejecutar el código en pantalla completa

```css
.navbar {
padding: 0!important; //El important fuerza a que se aplique el estilo, no es recomendable su uso
}


#navbarNav {
    background-color: #F4EFE1;
}

#navbarNav .navbar-brand,
#navbarNav .navbar-text {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A1C13;
}

#navbarNav .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3A1C13;
}

#navbarNav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
#navbarNav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #F4EFE1;
    font-family: "Playfair Display";
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #3A1C13;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.15/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
      

  
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <app-navbar>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['home']">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['menu']">Menú</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['about']">Sobre Nosotros</a>
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item">                                                      </li> -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
          </app-navbar>
        </div>
      
        <div class="col-12">
            <router-outlet>
              <br>
              
              <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center justify-content-lg-between">
        <div class="card col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1 justify-content-center">
            <!--ml-lg-3-->
            <img class="card-img-top pt-2 pb-2" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/PK_l1gDLbyQ/maxresdefault.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 fondo1 mt-1">
            <!--mr-lg-3-->
            <article>
                <h2>BASES</h2>
                <hr>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam tempora nemo ducimus quis obcaecati praesentium enim inventore molestias possimus asperiores, totam impedit, consectetur porro modi quo officia soluta rem iste!</p>
                <h3 class="firma">Quilia Lozano</h3>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
              
              
          </router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <app-footer>
              
              <footer class="page-footer font-small mdb-color lighten-3 mt-3 color">

    <div class="container text-center text-md-left">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mr-auto my-md-4 my-0 mt-4 mb-1 ml-3">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Información</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <p class="letras">Info de Me Tente</p>
            </div>
            <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">

            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 mx-auto my-md-4 my-0 mt-4 mb-1">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Dirección</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <ul class="list-unstyled" style="margin-left: -15px;">
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-home mr-3"></i> Montevideo, UY xxxxx, UY
                        </p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope mr-3"></i> info@example.com</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p class="letras">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone mr-3"></i> 09xxxxxxx</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr class="clearfix w-100 d-md-none">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center mx-auto my-4">
                <h5 class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase mb-4 letras">Siguenos</h5>
                <hr class="clearfix w-100">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/metentefood/">
                    <i class="socialmedia colorF animation fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/me_tente.food/?hl=es-la" class="ml-2">
                    <i class="socialmedia colorI animation fab fa-instagram"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<br>
              
          </app-footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.5.15/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias no sabia eso de bootstrap.  :)

Comment: Te recomiendo te des un recorrido a la documentación oficial de Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ (En su versión 4.1)